# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ Cannot SSH

Tags: pi-3

My Rspberry Pi 3 Model B+ has the SD card with the latest Raspbian lite OS. I connect it via the USB port of my Mac for the power supply and the Ethernet cable is connected to my Windows machine.

I can see the green light flashes for a while and then it goes off after say 20 seconds. I then see a constant red light. I then open putty on my Windows and try to ssh into the Pi. I also have an empty ssh file under the boot directory. When I now try to boot into the pi using putty, I get the following message:

```
Unable to open connection to raspberrypi.local Host does not exist
```

I even tried to just give raspberrypi instead of the raspberrypi.local, but nothing seems to work.

I tried to ping raspberrypi.local and raspberrypi, but nothing seems to work. I get a Host not found message back.

Any ideas as to what is wrong with this? How can I resolve this?

EDIT: I solved it. The problem was that my Windows laptop was not setting up any network with the Pi even though I had a LAN cable connected to the Pi from my Windows machine. My Windows laptop is connected to the home internet via WiFi.

Now, I connected the Pi directly on the router at my home and bang I can see the pi listed in the set of devices at my home and thus I was able to log in!

QUESTION:

My router is in the cellar, how can I now just use my Mac to give the Pi the needed internet connection? I don't want to go to the cellar every time I want to play with my Pi. Any ideas as to how I can make the Pi connect to the internet just using my Mac?

Comment: can you try using the IP address set on the pi?

Comment: If you setup Internet Connection Sharing on the Mac and plug in Ethernet cable it will work, but **WHY NOT** just connect the Pi3 WiFi to your network. PS I don't know which Mac, **BUT** trying to power a Pi from USB will cause problems; I am surprised it works at all!

Comment: pardon the correction, but that depends on the USB... new MacBooks will source 5 amps from the USB C port. And IIRC, the USB 3.1 spec calls for 5 amps.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, your RPi is connected to your WiFi router downstairs via Ethernet patch cable. If that's the case, then your RPi **should** already have an Internet connection, and your Mac has nothing to do with that!

In any case, here's how you check that:

1. `ssh` to your RPi
2. from your command line in your RPi, enter `ping -c 3 www.google.com`
3. if your `ping`s get a response; you're connected!

If you don't get a response, ask yourself these questions:

1. Is my RPi configured to use DHCP? (if not, fix this, or alternatively: **properly** configure a static IP address in RPi **and** your WiFi router)
2. Is my WiFi router properly configured to allow the RPi to "join" the network; e.g. it's acting as DHCP server and router, no MAC address blocking, etc.

If you still have issues, post details here and we'll help you sort it.

Comment: You can differentiate the a lack of connection from a lack of DNS service by using an IP address (e.g., `8.8.8.8`) with `ping` as well (you can also tell by the error message, but the easiest way to learn that is to infer it by trying both).

Comment: That's correct, but if he used the ip address, then we wouldn't know if his dhcp service was configured properly (i.e. supplies a DNS), and so there may still be other issues to smoke out . :)

Comment: Hence "by using an IP address with ping **as well**". ;)